# Prefetch a Cross Joined Subquery with Peewee Python ORM

Tags: python, sql, orm, peewee, prefetch

My models are:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    product_id = peewee.CharField(primary_key=True)
    list_price = peewee.FloatField()

class Week(BaseModel):
    week_date = peewee.DateField(primary_key=True)

class Plan(BaseModel):
    product = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Product, backref='plans')
    week = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Week, backref='plans')
    sales = peewee.FloatField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        primary_key = peewee.CompositeKey('product', 'week')

class Actual(BaseModel):
    product = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Product, backref='actuals')
    week = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Week, backref='actuals')
    sales = peewee.FloatField(null=True)
    price = peewee.FloatField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        primary_key = peewee.CompositeKey('product', 'week')

class Forecast(BaseModel):
    product = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Product, backref='forecasts')
    week = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Week, backref='forecasts')
    sales = peewee.FloatField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        primary_key = peewee.CompositeKey('product', 'week')
```

I do a query with the Plan class as my base, selecting from Product and Week to get all possible combinations, annotated with any existing actuals, plans, and forecasts.

```
query = Plan.select(
    Product.product_id,
    Week.week_date,
    Plan.sales.alias('plan_sales'),
    Actual.sales.alias('actual_sales'),
    Forecast.sales.alias('forecast_sales')
    ).from_(Product, Week
    ).join(Plan, "LEFT OUTER", 
        on=((Plan.week==Week.week_date)&
        (Plan.product==Product.product_id))
    ).join(Forecast, "LEFT OUTER", 
        on=((Forecast.week==Week.week_date)& 
        (Forecast.product==Product.product_id))
    ).join(Actual, "LEFT OUTER",
        on=((Actual.week==Week.week_date)& 
        (Actual.product==Product.product_id))
    )
```

This does what I wanted. I get Plan objects for all possible products and weeks, whether a plan, actual, or forecast exists or not.

However, the cross join is lost when I try to prefetch this query from Product or Week.

```
>>> query.where(Week.week_date=='2018-04-29').objects().count()
17

>>> weeks_with_plans = Week.select().prefetch(query.objects())
>>> weeks_with_plans[0]
<Week: '2018-04-29'>

>>> weeks_with_plans[0].plans
[<Plan: 'Pr01 2018-04-29'>, <Plan: 'Pr02 2018-04-29'>]
```

The cross joined query returns all 17 possible plan objects for week dated 2018-04-29, but when I take that same week with the query prefetched, only 2 objects get attached to the same week instance.

Peewee's prefetch_add_subquery() is adding to the WHERE clause of the original query:

```
AND ("plan"."week_id" IN (SELECT "week"."week_date" FROM "week"))
```

This limits the prefetch to the product/week combinations that actually exist in the plan table, eliminating the effect of the cross join. How can I *prefetch* the crossed combinations for a given Week or Product like I get from the original subquery?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're trying to do. I understand the first query - get sales details for all products (forecast, actual and planned). But I don't understand what you're trying to do with prefetch? Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi coleifer, thanks for responding, and thank you so much for peewee. The first query is a cross join, so it gives me all possible combinations of product and week, expressed as plan objects. However, not all of those plans actually exist in the plans table. I'm trying to select Weeks and prefetch that query, so that week_instance.plans will populate with the results of the first query for each week. However, I lose the "all possible combinations" because prefetch() limits the results to objects that actually exist in the plans table.

Comment: When I perform Week.select().prefetch(query.objects()), I originally expected that prefetch() would somehow see that Week is in the from_ clause of my query, and attach the results of my query to each week instance accordingly. However, I see that instead prefetch() has noticed that I used Plan.select() to initiate my query and therefore assumes it can attach my query to Week instances using the relationship between Week and Plan. My peewee query is giving me Plan() objects, but I did not actually select them FROM the plan table.

Comment: I am able to get the result I'm looking for if I manually attach the results of my query to each week instance: weeks = Week.select() plans = query.objects() for instance in weeks: instance.plans = [plan for plan in plans if plan.week_id==instance.week_date]. This is my solution for now. Is this the best solution?